# KendoUI window fixed position on page scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I have a long page with scroll bars. When I open a modal kenoWindow and scroll the page, the window goes off the viewing area. How can I force the window to stay where it is? I thought of making it's position fixed:

> ```
> div.k-window
> {
>     position:fixed !important;
> }
> ```

But if I try to move the window, it jumps down (depending on the scroll position of the page).

Any idea?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. Do you want the window to stay in the center or to stay wherever you placed it (the window can be dragged)?

Comment: I want it to stay wherever I placed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working with re-positioning the window on page scroll event.

```
var fixedPosWindows = null;
var currentWindowScrollPos;

function FixWindowPos(kwin) {
    if (fixedPosWindows === null) {
        fixedPosWindows = [];
        currentWindowScrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var diff = top - currentWindowScrollPos;
            for (var i = 0; i < fixedPosWindows.length ; i++) {
                var w = fixedPosWindows[i].parent();
                w.css("top", parseInt(w.css("top"), 10) + diff + "px");
            }
            currentWindowScrollPos = top;
        });
    }
    fixedPosWindows.push(kwin);
}
```

then I call the function for every window that I want to have fixed position:

```
var w = $("#window").kendoWindow();
FixWindowPos(w);
```

if you destroy a window, it will not remove from the array. so if it's a long living page with a lot of windows that are destroyed and recreated, it may have some performance isuues. But in most cases it's not a problem.

**Edit:**
Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodvcs/GXwfN/

Any better idea?

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier/better way. The snippet below will center the image on screen and position 20% from the top, even as you scroll:

```
$('#window').data('kendoWindow').center();

$('#window').closest(".k-window").css({
       position: 'fixed',
       margin: 'auto',
       top: '20%'
    });
```

Combined with position:fixed you should find it behaves as you are looking for, and with much less code.

Comment: Then u can't drag the window right? did u try that? I think it's not so different from my workaround in the question.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell that was what you were trying to do form your question. No, it would be fixed (and draggable left or right) but would move when you scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this solution, but it involves jQuery position

`var kendo_wnd = $("#window")
    .kendoWindow({
        title: "Title of Window",
        modal: true,
        visible: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        open: function (e) {
            var currentWindow = $(this.element);
            currentWindow.closest(".k-window").position({ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }).css("position", "fixed");
            // Some Code;
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow");`

Answer (score 0):

I liked KakashiJack's solution, but ended up simplifying it a bit more. Using Kendo's built in center function instead of JQuery's position.

Using the Kendo example at
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/window/overview#initialize-window-center-and-configure-button-click-action

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var win = $("#window").kendoWindow({
        height: "200px",
        title: "Centered Window",
        visible: false,
        width: "200px",
        open: function (e) {$(this.element).closest(".k-window").css("position", "fixed")}
    }).data("kendoWindow");
});

$("#openButton").click(function(){
    var win = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
    win.center();
    win.open();
});
```